# Display nested object dynamically to fill its inputs with data

Tags: angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular 7 as a front end for my project and want to display input fields for user to fill data using reactive forms.
The problem is that the object i am trying to display is having multiple layers,so the first layer can have input which can be dynamically added (so that i use fb.array when building the form) and object which can be added dynamically with all things it contains which can have the same or even a different structure and so on .

i have achieved that but through static way that includes the following:
-determine how many inputs and objects can be added dynamically (i can know that through an attribute in the object and the inputs which have same structures but different types ,input,list,object....),
-add nested form for each object with its children.
 which means i have to add some code when ever the object getting deeper. 
How can i achieve that dynamically so that i pass the object regardless of how much layers is has , and display it as a nested forms and can that be done with reactive form or i have to change the entire method?

This is what i have already tried :

```
 this.check = this.objects.filter(e=>e.Max>1);

     if(this.check.length === 1){
      this.parentA=this.check[0];
      this.childrenA=this.parentA[0].filter(e=>e.type != "object");
       this.form = this.fb.group({
            'A': this.fb.array([
              this.initA(),
            ])
          });
     }else if(this.check.length === 2){
       .
       .
        this.form = this.fb.group({
        'A': this.fb.array([
          this.initB()
        ])
       });
    }

initA() {

    const elementFormGroup = this.fb.group({}); 
    this.childrenA.forEach(e => {

        eFormGroup.addControl(e.Name, 
       this.fb.control([], Validators.required));
      }
}

initY() {debugger    
    const elementFormGroup = this.fb.group({});
    this.childrenB.forEach(e => {
        elementFormGroup.addControl(e.Name, 
        this.fb.control([], Validators.required));     
    });

    elementFormGroup.addControl('A', this.fb.array([
      this.initA()
    ]))
    return elementFormGroup;
  }
.
.
.
.
```

I would appreciate any help because i am really stuck at this way.
Thank you.